# How to use Variable variables in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to use variable variables in smarty. I know that we can use it in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). But I am unable to find any way to achieve the same in Smarty template file. Consider the below scenario.

I have multiple variables which I pass from PHP file to Smarty tpl file. All these variables name have some similar pattern. e.g. `$test_1`, `$test_2`, `$test_3` and so on.

This is how, actually I am trying to achieve it. Here, `$COUNTER` represents 1, 2, 3....

```
 {$SELECTED_VALUE = "test_{$COUNTER}"}
 {$$SELECTED_VALUE|@print_r}
```

But when I try to print it out, it gives me error

```
Syntax Error in template "test.tpl" on line 127 "{$$SELECTED_VALUE|@print_r}" - Unexpected "$", expected one of: "{" , "identifier"
```

Now, in PHP, I can get the values of these variables using double `$$` symbols. But I am unable to find any way to achieve the same in a smarty tpl file.

I have gone through these links, but couldn't understand anything out of it.

[Variable Variable in Smarty Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962650/variable-variable-in-smarty-templates)

[Dynamics variables in smarty in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933787/dynamics-variables-in-smarty-in-loop)

Kindly guide me here, if it is possible.

Comment: why you want get the $$selected_value

Comment: @sree, basically, as I have mentioned above, this $$selected_value contains string which will be 'test1', 'test2' ..... which are the names of the variables which I am passing to the smarty tpl file. And I want to access these variables data.

Comment: In nearly all cases where you have a list of variable variables like this, it is better to just have an array. Then all the native functionality for arrays is available to you, and no extra magic is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I have found the solution. As I have mentioned above, I have these dynamically created and assigned `$test_1`, `$test_2`, `$test_3`,.... to smarty tpl file. So to use these variables dynamically, I have taken followed approach.

```
{for $counter=1 to $total}
      {$test_{$counter}}
 {/for}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a loop in your tpl file below
    For example, lets say $count = 10;

```
     {for $foo=1 to $count}
          <li>{$foo}</li>
     {/for}
```

Comment: I think you are not getting what I asked above. Forget about the loop, kindly let me know how to use Variable variable in Smarty tpl file as we use in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
{$x = ['foo', 'bar']}
{${$x}|print_r}
```